# make that when you click on the items inside the block, another block appears (each has its own)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There is a main unit that has 3 div. You need to click on each of the div's to open its content, and the main block together with the internal ones closed. In other words, only the opened block should remain on the page by clicking on it. I don't know how to implement this. Especially to open the content for this div, and not one for all.

[image]

I tried to explain it all in the picture.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Seems like a standard show/hide kind of thing would work here. Click on a blue rectangle, show the orange block, hide the blue rectangles. There are a few hundred questions about doing that in React on Stack Overflow I'd expect..

Comment: I know how to make some kind of block appear when you click. But I don't know how to make sure that everyone has their own content. And I also don't know how to hide the main block. I install an event handler on the internal div and can only remove it. But I need to remove the main block.

I'm still a newbie.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you attached an event handler to the (blue) divs? Is the handler firing when you click on them? Which part specifically is giving you a problem? You may want to review the Stackoverflow [help], [ask], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask]

Comment: Yeah, I attached an event handler to the blue div. I'm getting the same block. And it has to be unique for each blue block. And I also can't remove the main block after pressing the blue one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you are looking for ? [repro on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-uu3b3h?file=index.js)

Here is the code if you can't access stackblitz:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

const App = () => {
  // Hide/show main blocks
  const commonAction = () => {
    document.getElementById("container").classList.toggle("flex-col");
    Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("block")).forEach(el => {
      el.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  };

  // On click on the main block
  const enlarge = e => {
    commonAction();

    // Just show the one we clicked
    e.target.classList.remove("hidden");
    // Enlarge it
    e.target.classList.add("enlarge");
    // show/hide its details
    e.target.childNodes[1].classList.toggle("hidden");
  };

  // On click on the details
  const hide = e => {
    // Hide it
    e.target.classList.add("hidden");
    // reset main blocks to their original state
    commonAction();
    //reset main clicked block to its normal state
    const parent = e.target.closest(".block");
    parent.classList.remove("hidden");
    parent.classList.remove("enlarge");

    e.stopPropagation();
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div id="container">
        <div className="block" onClick={enlarge}>
          Content 1
          <div className="block-content hidden" onClick={hide}>
            Content details 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="block" onClick={enlarge}>
          Content 2
          <div className="block-content hidden" onClick={hide}>
            Content details 2
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="block" onClick={enlarge}>
          Content 3
          <div className="block-content hidden" onClick={hide}>
            Content details 1
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

css :

```
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 200px;
}

.flex-col{
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container > * {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 25%;
  background-color: #6dd4fd;
}

.block-content {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffb35c;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
}

.hidden{
  visibility: hidden;
  height:0px !important;
}

.enlarge{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: After we clicked, a completely different block should appear, but now the same one should appear, only for the whole page. Can you redo it, please? I can't do it myself. But this is almost the right thing to do.

Comment: You're amazing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry. why when I click on 'block after click' again it produces an error
Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined

Comment: @JessicaCornish It's done, i was working on it sorry ;) But it's pretty disgusting to do it like that, but it do the job, i'll edit my answer to add the new code